# Springboot LDAP close user session

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap

I am trying to close a user session opened through LDAP class after 5 seconds but it's not working and cannot figure out why. I am editing my class this way:

```
@Bean
public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
    LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
    contextSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("ldap.url"));
    contextSource.setBase(env.getProperty("ldap.userSearchBase"));
    contextSource.setUserDn(env.getProperty("ldap.managerDn"));
    contextSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("ldap.managerPassword"));     
    
    contextSource.setPooled(false);
    Map<String, Object> environment = new HashMap<>();
    environment.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout", "5000");
    environment.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout", "5000");
    contextSource.setBaseEnvironmentProperties(environment);
    contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
    
    return contextSource;
}
```

Any idea why this is not working? thanks!

Comment: What's the operation you are trying to do? ldapsearch? ldapbind? either way ldap connections closes itself after any operation, an alternative would be to use org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.closeContext(DirContext), to mannualy close the created context.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the operation I'm trying to do it's just closing the user's session when he navigates more than n minutes on the application.

Comment: both these entries DOES not end the user session:     environment.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout", "5000"); this one is triggered if the connection didn't succed after 5000, which i imagine is not your case.
    environment.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout", "5000"); and this one is triggered only when a read operation takes more thatn 5000, which is also not your case, i recommend using something like com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout , which sets a idle time after wich the open connection is closed, this could be helpful if you are using ldapbind operation.

Comment: However your exacte need will be somthing that set the maximum lifetime of a ldap connection, which i dont think exists in com.sun.jndi.ldap, but definitly exists in spring, you need to use a timer and function like this  ctx.close();